# We can not remove or move category in category tree by using install scripts?

Tags: magento2, certification

We can not remove or move the category in the category tree by using install scripts?

this question had asked in Magento 2 professional developer Exam.

can anyone explain this?

Comment: Hi, This may be totally unrelated comment, however I would like to know what other questions have appeared in the Certifier Professional Developer Exam. Do you happen to remember the kind of questions that appear? It would be really helpful if you can detail us your experience to all the people out here who are aiming to clear the certification.

Comment: @nikin I am preparing for the exam and i am found this question from others who have attempted the exam.

Comment: if anyone have any explanation for this, then please provide us